# disjointness in logics with higher order plurals

Tags: logic

The [SEP article on plural quantification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/) has a [section on higher-order plurals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/#HighLevePlurQuan).

First a word on notation, I use ∈ to denote member of an individual in a plural individual, and ⊕ to denote XOR.

When studying a formalism with higher-order plurals, does it make sense to insist that higher-level plurals be disjoint or does it make sense not to impose such a condition?

Have disjoint and non-disjoint flavors of higher-order logic with plural quantifiers both been studied?

Quoting from the article, for convenience

> What is relevant for present purposes is whether there is some form of
> “super-plural” quantification that stands to ordinary plural
> quantification as ordinary plural quantification stands to singular
> quantification. If so, let’s call this second-level plural
> quantification. More generally, we may attempt to introduce plural
> quantification of any finite level. This would result in a theory
> which for technical purposes is just like a simple type theory (Hazen
> 1997: 247; Linnebo 2003: sect. IV; Rayo 2006).

Following the notation from the article, we use doubled variables xx to denote plural variables. For instance, the statement below the left-hand side of (102) is equivalent to the right hand side, with D being our domain of discourse.

```
(102)  ∀xx.F(xx)   if and only if   ∀w : Set[D] . w ≠ {} ∧ F(w)
```

So, quantifying over a plural variable is not exactly the same thing as quantifying over all sets, since the empty set is excluded.

Breaking a bit with the article, I'll use x3 to denote plurals of plurals.

There are two natural ways to generalize what quantifying over x3 means.

We can assert disjointness (104) or not assert disjointness (103).

```
(103) ∀x3.F(x3)   if and only if  ∀w : Set[Set[D] \ {}] . w ≠ {} ∧ F(x3)

(104) ∀x3.F(x3)   if and only if  
(104)        ∀w : Set[Set[D] \ {}] . w ≠ {} ∧ (∀u∈w.∀v∈w.u=v⊕u⋂w={}) ∧ F(x3)
```

The examples given in the SEP article seems to suggest that disjointness is a key feature of higher order plural quantification.

In example (201) from the SEP article, with original citation included, it seems obvious that an individual cannot be on two teams at once. In example (202), it seems clear that same Cheerio cannot be present in two groups of Cheerios.

> (201) These people, those people, and these other people compete
> against each other. (Linnebo and Nicolas 2008)

And the second example

> (202) For instance, the second-level plurality based on Cheerios
> organized as oo oo oo should be no more ontologically problematic than
> the first-level plurality based on the same objects organized as
> oooooo, although the former has an additional level of structure or
> articulation (Linnebo 2003: 87–8).

I can't find any examples or language that talk explicitly about requiring disjointness, or the consequences of different flavors of mandated disjointness for higher-order plurals.

Comment: I don't think disjointness is an essential feature of higher order plural quantification. The two examples given in the SEP article do involve disjointness, but we could imagine others that do not. For example, we could speak of the multiple of pluralities that could arise when choosing a soccer team of 11 players from a squad of 15.

Comment: That's an interesting example, but I think it shows that disjointness does influence how we use language (or at least one uses English). I think in that case I'd be more likely to describe that entity as `15!/(11!*4!)` ways of picking a team or `15!/(11!*4!)` possible teams rather than `15!/(11!*4!)` soccer teams. The fact that there's so much potential overlap between different possible teams makes describing them as *teams* without qualifying *teams* in any way seem odd and misleading.

Comment: My hunch is that violating disjointness prevents *simultaneous instantiation* of the entities in a higher-order plural and that that fact is relevant, but I don't have any real evidence or a citation to back it up.